# ScrollView diorders and removes the contents of relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am having problem in `ScrollView`. Without using `scrollView` my App gives such kind of layout[image: Preview without using <code>ScrollView</code>]

but when I adds `ScrollView` Tag on the regular code that looks likes

```
`<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="578dp" >
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/DiscountRate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:text="Discount Rate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:text="Results" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DiscountRate"
    android:text="Sex" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:text="Date of Birth" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dateOfBirth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateOfBirth"
    android:text="Date of Trial" />
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dateOfTrial"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" /></RelativeLayout></ScrollView>`
```

then output is disorders [image: Output after adding scrollView tag]

Kindly help me why this is happening.

Comment: Remove this property  android:layout_centerVertical="true" into your both datepickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Remove this property

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

into your both datepickers on your code i hope this will be worked

Answer (score 0):

```
try this..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="578dp" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Discount Rate" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/DiscountRate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DiscountRate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="Sex" />

         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="Date of Birth" />

          <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dateOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
             />

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dateOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="Date of Trial" />

            <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dateOfTrial"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/results"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Results" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```